# How to merge MultiIndex Dataframes with weights in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I have 3 multi-index dataframes that are structured like this:

```
     Dataframe1:

     Date      IDs     Values
     Date1     ID4     0.5
               ID5     2.3
               ID6     3.1
     Date2     ID1     1.2
               ID4     5.1
     ...


     Dataframe2:

     Date      IDs     Values
     Date1     ID1     2.5
               ID2     3.3
               ID4     4.1
     Date2     ID3     5.2
               ID4     1.1
     ...

same for dataframe3
```

The dates and ID's mostly repeat across each instantiation, but there might be some that are not exactly lined up.

I need to merge all 3 into one dataframe that has the same structure, but with each id/date matching pair added up with weights (so a weighted average).

Is there an easy dataframe command to perform this?

Comment: How do you calculate the weighted average here? I dont see any weight. Do you mean just simply take the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, we can do the following.

First concatenate the dataframes to one dataframe with [`pandas.concatenate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and at the same time we reset the index with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index).

Then we use [`Dataframe.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the columns `Date & IDs` and take the `mean` of `Values`:

```
df_all = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()])

df_all = df_all.groupby(['Date', 'IDs'], as_index=False)['Values'].mean()
```

---

Which yields:

```
print(df_all)
    Date  IDs  Values
0  Date1  ID1     2.5
1  Date1  ID2     3.3
2  Date1  ID4     2.3
3  Date1  ID5     2.3
4  Date1  ID6     3.1
5  Date2  ID1     1.2
6  Date2  ID3     5.2
7  Date2  ID4     3.1
```

Comment: Great, this seems to work perfectly.  In the first concatenation, do all the individual ID values remain in the concatenated dataframe, with no operation performed on them?   Finally, if I did want to put anything other than equal-weights, is there a way to use the group-by function, or would it become much more complex?  Say, if the weights were (0.1, 0.4, 0.5).  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help. Yes the first line will keep all rows. So you could perform a weighted average, but that would make the question different. I would post a new question for that. Hint, you have to use [`np.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) for that @SingularityFuture